# Flexbox container is not occupying entire width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making a project using flexbox. The header is not occupying the entire width. It is leaving white spaces from both sides and above like this:

[image]

I tried changing some code but it's not working. How do I make it occupy entire width ? I would appreciate the help.

The code is this:

```css
header {
  background: url(./imgs/beef-cotlet-burger-with-sauce-wooden-board.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.flex-items:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  order: 0;
  background-color: purple;
}

.flex-items:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  order: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.flex-items:nth-child(3) {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  order: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.flex-container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-items2:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  order: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="/fontawesome-free-6.0.0-web/fontawesome-free-6.0.0-web/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/fontawesome-free-6.0.0-web/fontawesome-free-6.0.0-web/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/fontawesome-free-6.0.0-web/fontawesome-free-6.0.0-web/css/brands.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/fontawesome-free-6.0.0-web/fontawesome-free-6.0.0-web/css/solid.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <title>Burguer Restaurant</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="flex-container">

      <!--Logo-->
      <div class="flex-items">
        <div style="background-color: red;">
          <img src="./imgs/hamburguer 64.png">
          <h3 class="logo">fast food</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Navbar-->
      <div class="flex-items">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <a href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">Pages</a>
            <a href="">Our Offer</a>
            <a href="">Galleries</a>
            <a href="">Blog</a>
            <a href="">Shop</a>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <!--Icons-->
      <div class="flex-items">
        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="flex-container2">
      <div class="flex-items2">
        <h3 style="background-color: red;">fast food burguers</h3>
        <h1>BEST BURGUERS<br>IN GALAXY</h1>
        <button>OUR MENU</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </header>
  ´sdjg´sdgj
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add `html, body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: You are using some `<br>` and your navbar is basically divided into three sections and because you are using a `space-between` on the parent container containing the navbar items you are encountering the unwanted space.

Comment: @AliMustafa I'll take a look. Thanks!